# How many rotations would a mesh need to go through to experience noticable entropy?

Tags: mesh, vertices

A thought just occurred to me while I was measuring a cylinder's diameter; I checked the diameter diagonally (i.e. besides the accurate diameter measured between vertices on the axes, I also measured vertices whose x and y positions both changed) and I found that my hunch was right: the points around the cylinder are not exactly the same distance from their opposite; they were extremely close but not exact. This made sense since the numbers have only have so many significant digits.

This got me wondering: does this mean that every time a mesh is rotated, aside from rotation at multiples of 90 degrees, the distance between vertices is altered slightly (when I say "mesh," I mean in edit mode, rotating in object mode doesn't make any permanent changes to the mesh; one of a cube's vertices is still at (-1,-1,1) in edit mode even if the object is on an angle)? Because if it does, after A LOT of rotations, the mesh would become distorted because of entropy, yeah? And if so, how long could you keep using the same object before it becomes visably wonky?

Comment: Since the rotation math uses periodic trig methods not sure it matters too much.  If crunched in python 3.7 interpreter  `sin(2e10 * p)` is significantly larger  than `sin(2 * pi)`  (approx. `1e10` times)  If the internal logic simply maps any rotations to, for example its equivalent in `[-pi, pi]` (not sure you can even "wind up" quaternions) then cannot see entropy being very significant.

Comment: From what I understand you will only lose precision in the degrees you are rotation the mesh with. That is, the number of steps you can rotate the mesh in will reduce as you increase the degrees. Set the rotation to Axis Angle and go nuts!